# Update aggregate root with child entities using repository pattern

Tags: sql, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I will use the standard example of Invoice and invoiceLineItems. So I have a single repository for the invoices because the invoice is the aggregate root. Creating a whole invoice and deleting an invoice is pretty easy. What about updating an invoice?

Maybe I shouldn't be thinking so "low level" but I can't imagine a nice way to handle this. Here is my pseudo code for this operation

```
public void Update(Invoice inv)
{
    var dbVersion = GetInvoice(id);
    foreach(var lineItem in inv.LineItems)
    {
        if (lineItem not in dbVersion)
        {
            InsertLineItem(lineItem);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateLineItem(lineItem);
        }
    }

    foreach(var lineItem in dbVersion)
    {
        if (lineItem not in inv)
        {
            DeleteLineItem(lineItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I am imagining the queries this thing needs to produce and it seems very inefficient.

- Select statements to re materialize the whole invoice.
- Update statement for the whole invoice (regardless if anything on the invoice changed)
- Insert statement for each line item that is new
- Update statement for each line item that is already there (regardless if anything changed)
- Delete statement for each line item that is missing

Of course you wouldn't have to generate an update statement for the whole invoice and for the InvoiceLineItem but that would require you to check all the properties in each.

If you however went the IvoiceLineItemRepo you would only update when a user performed an action that would necessitate the update. So if the user updated just a line then there would only be a single update and for that line item and you wouldn't have to check for changes you could assume that it had changed.

Is there a nicer way of handling the updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can first delete LineItem collection and then insert new collection like all-delete-orphan in hibernate.

```
deleteAllLineItemsByInvoiceId(Long id);
insertAllLineItems(List<LineItem> lineItems);
```